# Correct way to share parent child relationship in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am building a model for a purchase order.

When I have my view render the header of a purchase order, I would like to be able
to pass the id of that purchase order to the directive that I have constructed for the line items. Ie:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($timeout) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.po = {};

  init();

  function init() {
    $timeout(function() {
      vm.po.id = 123;
    }, 1000);
  }

});


app.directive('lineItems', LineItems);

function LineItems() {

  var directive = {
    scope: {
      poId: '@'
    },
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<div class="red" ng-repeat="l in vm.lineItems">{{ l || json }}</div>',
    controller: LineItemsController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };
  return directive;

}

LineItemsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$q'];

function LineItemsController($scope, $q) {

  //Private
  var vm = this;

  //Properties
  vm.lineItems = [];

  //Methods

  init();

  function init() {
    // normally I would load these using a data service and the bound Id
    vm.lineItems = [{
      id: 1,
      desc: "Item1",
      poId: $scope.poId
    }, {
      id: 2,
      desc: "Item2",
      poId: $scope.poId
    }, {
      id: 3,
      desc: "Item3",
      poId: $scope.poId
    }]
  }

}
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <p>Hello Purchase Order : {{ vm.po.id }}</p>

  <line-items po-Id="{{vm.po.id}}"></line-items>
</body>

</html>
```

When the line item directive is initialized, it loads it's own data to display the line items and allow for editing.  But when I try and do this, the purchaseOrderId is never bound at the time the directive is trying to render itself.

Am I taking a wrong approach?  Is there an easier way to accomplish this with good separation of responsibility between those two objects?  Both are controlled via separate restful endpoints, but have relationships with each other.

edit:  I'm guessing I need to delay my init until a valid po-id is bound?  Would I do that with a watch?

Comment: Can you share the code for your directive?

Answer (score 1):

When you define your directive, you should set the scope property as follows:

```
scope: {
    poId: "@"
}
```

This way you will bind the poId to an attribute of the element with the same name (i dont remember if the camel case conversion would also happen here, so you should try "poId" and "po-id");

Hope this helps.

Comment: `poId` would be correct inside the directive and would map to `po-id` in the html.

Comment: I had that much figured out.  I edited my question above to illustrate. I think it's just a matter of timing, but I'm not sure if there is a standard approach to these types of shared data.

Comment: If you are using angualar routing, you could use the resolve functionallity provided, check this link out for more info :http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx